# How do I write a user defined function to count the first name in the NAME and exactly match the score with respect to first name in the score column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Sam, Josh | 0 |
| Sam, Kay | 1 |
| Sam, Jane | 0 |
| Jay, Kane | 1 |
| Jay, Kris | 0 |

I need the output like this
Output:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Sam team members | 1 |
| Jay team members | 1 |

Comment: can you please be a bit more specific what your goal is ? just from the title of the question it is not quite clear. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You want to first go through names and then sum all the scores.
First map the split function across names column

```
dataframe["Name"] = dataframe["Name"].map(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])
```

then you group by name and sum all the Scores

```
dataframe = dataframe.groupby("Name").sum()
```

If you want to Name column to be the way it is in your example you can map through it again and use f string to edit it

```
dataframe["Name"] = dataframe["Name"].map(lambda x: f"{x} team members")
```